# Work in conical pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A conical pendulum consists of a light string, with a length $$,
and a small ball with the mass $$. The ball moves with its
constant speed in a circular path with radius $$ in one
horizontal plane.

(a) What work does the string tension on the ball do then
the ball moves half a revolution from the position shown in
the figure? Does the lace tension do a positive job, one
negative work, or no work at all?

(b) What work does the gravity of the ball do when the ball moves halfway
laps from the position shown in the figure? Does gravity do a positive job,
a negative job, or no job at all?
Motivate your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) The string tension makes an angle of 90° with the circular path of the small ball at any given time in a conical pendulum. So the work done by the tension force is 0.

(b) The force of gravity is in the vertical direction which is again perpendicular to the horizontal plane in which the circular path of the small ball of the conical pendulum lies. So the work done by the force of gravity is also 0.

I hope this answer helps you.